# Nginx hosting Signalr Blazor Wasm App: 405 Method not Allowed

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, nginx, blazor, asp.net-core-signalr

This request from the Blazor WebAssembly App served by Nginx returns the 405 Method Not Allowed error (POST):

> http://localhost:4000/chatHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1

Researching I discovered that when Nginx is working as a reverse proxy, it is necessary to upgrade the headers, but that is not my case. Nginx here is working as a Web Server. Here is my nginx.conf:

```
events {}

http {
    include mime.types;
    types {
        application/wasm wasm;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my back-end api Startup config:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSignalR();

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .SetIsOriginAllowed(host => true);
            });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

What am I missing here? Do I have to map the specific location "/chatHub" in nginx.conf to work with webSockets somehow?

Ps.: I am using Docker containers (docker-compose).

Answer (score 2):

So, the problem was not Nginx afterall. I was sending a request to the wrong port. The Blazor app shouldn't pass through Nginx but request directly to the back-end.

I was using the **NavigationManager** class to get a URI to the back-end, but I didn't realize that it by default points to the **origin of the front-end** which gave me the wrong URI. I was following the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor-webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) but I had to make some modifications because I'm not using the Asp.net hosted version of Blazor Wasm.

The problem though is the order of endpoints registration. **The hubs must be registered after the controllers** otherwise the browser will throw a CORS error. So the correct is:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
...

server {
    listen 80;

        location /chatHub/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        }

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        }
    }
}

...
```

On docker-compose.yml make sure you got

```
...
ports:
  - "4000:4000"
...
```